# VBA - Reconciliation of Large datasets

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have two files with 50k+ rows.
They both include an order code. In one file that would be Right("AQ column", 7) and the other one would have it in column C.
I would like to match an order code, and compare if the values are the same. Also, in the second file, there should be a check in a different column to see if there is a string matching "SETTLED" as there are duplicate order codes in that file.

I have tried a few approaches, Ill paste a not so efficient one below, in order for what I am trying to fix to be clear.
revnW and Wpay are the 2 different workbooks

```
DesLRow = revnW.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
SrcLRow = wPay.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to DesLrow
 for j = 3 to srcLrow
  If right(revnW.Sheets(1).Cells(i,43).text, 7) = wPay.Sheets(1).Cells(j,3).text And_
 Instr(wPay.Sheets(1).Cells(j,5).text, "SETTLED") And value <> value 2 (pseudo code) Then


Do stuff (get transaction number, and some other things)
      exit for   
      next j
Next i
```

I know this code is not efficient, I have tried to load the columns into an array, but then I could only compare one column, and not the values etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use ADODB within VBA? Using database-based approach will be the best option for you. Any VBA solution using 2 loops will be much, much slower!

Comment: See my answer here for an approach using a pair of Dictionary objects  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777978/vba-comparing-two-2d-arrays-rows-vba-throws-type-mismatch-declarations-ok/35778287#35778287   It will be a lot faster than your current code.

Comment: Hi Tim, that looks very interesting, if I understand correctly would this be something like an array with 3 dimensions? each array "position" would consist of 3 columns?

Comment: You would need a modification of that code since one of your "keys" is only a substring of the cell value.  Your "keys" would be the order number, and the values would be row numbers within each dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but should give you a starting point:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim desLRow As Long, srcLRow As Long
    Dim dictDest As Object, dictSrc As Object

    With revnW.Sheets(1)
       Set dictDest = RowMap(.Range(.Cells(2, 43), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 43).End(xlUp)), 7)
    End With
    With wPay.Sheets(1)
       Set dictSrc = RowMap(.Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)))
    End With

    For Each k In dictDest.keys
        If dictSrc.exists(k) Then

            'do the rest of your checks here....

            Debug.Print "Match between Dest " & dictDest(k).Address & " and " & _
                        dictSrc(k).Address
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

Here's the "map" function:

```
'Get a "map" of row keys to the
'    rows where they are located (just maps the first cell in each row)
' "rng" is the range to be mapped
' "numright" -  pass a number if you just want a part of the value to be mapped
Function RowMap(rng As Range, Optional numRight As Long = 0)
    Dim rv, nr As Long, nc As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim k, data

    Set rv = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    data = rng.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        k = data(r, 1)
        If numRight > 0 Then k = Right(k, numRight)
        If rv.exists(k) Then
            Set rv(k) = Application.Union(rv(k), rng.Columns(1).Cells(r))
        Else
            rv.Add k, rng.Columns(1).Cells(r)
        End If
    Next r
    Set RowMap = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, Ill take a look at it later today , but it looks like exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Fantastic Tim. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

I would process the data with some SQL.
Here is an example to join two sheets in a third one :

```
Sub QueryExample()

  Const SQL_JOIN_SHEETS = _
    "SELECT * " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] a INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] b " & _
    "ON a.ID = b.ID "

  SqlExec source:=ThisWorkbook, sql:=SQL_JOIN_SHEETS, target:=[Sheet3]

End Sub

''
' Executes a query on a workbook.
' @source {Workbook}  Workbook loaded by the SQL engine
' @target {Worksheet} Worksheet to display the result
' @sql {String} SQL query
''
Sub SqlExec(source As workbook, sql As String, target As Worksheet)
  Dim rs As Object, conn$
  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
  conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
    source.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

  ' execute the query
  rs.Open sql, conn

  ' copy the headers to the target sheet
  target.Cells.Clear
  For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
    target.Cells(1, i).Value = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
  Next

  ' copy the values to the target sheet
  target.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

  ' dispose
  rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I dont really know enough of SQL to understand this code. What does it exactly do?

Comment: It combines 2 tables into a third one. For the basics : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp