# Getting the header with data from access database

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have written a piece of VBA code that loops through a list of access database queries and copies them into one excel workbook. The code is working perfectly, but I can not figure out how to include the headers into the data when copied to excel workbook.

```
Sub AccessQuerie()

    Dim A As Object
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim sheetNum As Integer
    Dim queryList

    Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("macro.xlsm")

    A.Visible = False
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\accessdb") 'Access database file path

    queryList = wkb.Sheets("settings").Range("K28:K43").Value

    sheetNum = 3

    For Each Item In queryList
        A.DoCmd.OpenQuery (Item)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetNum)

        Dim rs As Object
        Set rs = A.CurrentDb().QueryDefs(Item).OpenRecordset()

        ws.Range("A1").Value = Item

        If Not rs.EOF Then
            ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If

        rs.Close

        sheetNum = sheetNum + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

my output data looks like this

```
10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10
```

but Im looking to get this output

```
NumData NumData NumData NumData NumData
10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10
10  10  10  10  10
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: To get the names, read the property `rs.Fields`. For an example, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877042/vba-reconciliation-of-large-datasets/35879567#35879567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add field names in separate piece of code.

```
Dim field
Dim lCol As Long

lCol = 0
For Each field In rs.Fields
    ws.Range("A2").Offset(, lCol) = field.Name
    lCol = lCol + 1
Next field
```

and not forget to move rest of data one row down:

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ws.Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the fields in your query like this

```
Dim qtQueryDefs As QueryDef
Dim rsRs As Recordset
Dim fField As Field

For Each qtQueryDefs In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    Set rsRs = qtQueryDefs.OpenRecordset()
    For Each fField In rsRs.Fields
        Debug.Print fField.Name
    Next
Next
```